# How can I relate an edge/relationship to a node which contains information about that edge?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, data-modeling, graph-databases

I have to store biological interactions in a Neo4j database. For example, consider a scenario where I have two types of nodes, `Protein` & `Experiment` and a relationship `INTERACTS_WITH`. The relationship exists as `(Protein)-[INTERACTS_WITH]-(Protein)`. Now, the `INTERACTS_WITH` also relates to `Experiment` because this biological interaction was observed in that experiment.

I need to relate the `INTERACTS_WITH` relationship to the `Experiments`.

One way to achieve this can be to store the ID of all such `Experiments` in an array type property of the `INTERACTS_WITH` relationship. But that will be just like storing the Primary Key of an entity as Foreign Key of another entity in the relational database, which I want to avoid.

Another way can be to create an `Interaction` node for each pair of interacting genes and then relate it to the two `Proteins` and the `Experiments`. But an interaction is possible between two `Protein` nodes only, so I will have to programmatically put a constraint on the number of `Protein` nodes that relate to an `Interaction` node. This approach is also not good because `INTERACTS_WITH` is actually a relationship and perhaps it will be not a good idea to model it as a node.

Is there a better, graphical way to do this? If not, which of the above two approaches will be better?

Comment: I propose 

(i:Interaction)<-[:IDK]-(p2:Protein)
(i:Interaction)<-[:IDK]-(p1:Protein)
(e:Experiment)<-[:SEEN_IN]-(i:Interaction)

Comment: To make sure there is only 2 Proteins in an interaction, trust your UI.
Also, you can make batch queries, and react (report, email) to the user who created the interaction (provided you store it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Another way can be to create an Interaction node for each pair of
>   interacting genes and then relate it to the two Proteins and the
>   Experiments.

I believe that it is a very good approach to solve your problem.

> But an interaction is possible between two Protein nodes only, so I
>   will have to programmatically put a constraint on the number of
>   Protein nodes that relate to an Interaction node.

There is nothing to do. Programmers do it all the time! For example: What guarantees do you have about how many INTERACTS_WITH relationships exists between a pair of  Protein nodes? Probably you take care about it at creation time.

> This approach is also not good because INTERACTS_WITH is actually a
>   relationship and perhaps it will be not a good idea to model it as a
>   node.

Think about it: if your `INTERACTS_WITH` relationship needs to be related with more than two nodes maybe you are modeling a node as a relationship, right?

*Tip: take a look in the section **Graph modeling – best practices and
pitfalls** of the book Learning Neo4j (by Rik Van Bruggen) and in the section **Common Modeling Pitfalls** of the book Graph Databases (by Ian Robinson, Jim Webber & Emil Eifrem). This can be enlightening. You can download the two books in the Neo4j site [here](https://neo4j.com/books/).*